# Running multiple Spring Boot apps in a single EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-ec2, dns, amazon-cloudfront

I am trying to deploy multiple spring boot web applications with embedded tomcat in a single EC2 instance.

With an embedded tomcat (I prefer to decouple my apps runtime), each one of these apps should be running on a different port (let's say 8081, 8082 and 8083).

For each of these apps I would like to point a domain:

- app1.domaine.com should point to APP1 running on 8081
- app2.domaine.com should point to APP2 running on 8082
- app3.domaine.com should point to APP3 running on 8083

Do you think it's possible to go ahead with a single instance ?

I am not sure if the CloudFront+ELB could do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this with a Classic Load Balancer, but you can do it with a Application Load Balancer.

ALB supports host-based routing, so create one route for each hostname.  Each route will have an associated target group, and all 3 target groups can point to the same instance but different ports.

You can do the same thing with paths if you don' want different domains - i.e. you can have domaine.com/app1, domaine.com/app2 and domaine.com/app3 each associated with different target groups.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I will give it a try with the ALB and let you know.

Comment: I have been to the Rules menu but never thought of adding new rules so I didn't saw the filter by host. It should work now. Appreciate it !!

Comment: Hi chris could you please share some example ... It seems to be interesting.